# How can I fix sandbox error on SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, sandbox, swi-prolog

**I'm trying this code on SWI-Prolog:**

```
go :-
    write('What is the patient''s name? '),
    read(Patient),
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    write_list([Patient,'probably has ',Disease,'.']),nl.

go :-
    write('Sorry, I don''t seem to be able to'),nl,
    write('diagnose the disease.'),nl.

symptom(Patient,fever) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a fever (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,rash) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a rash (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,headache) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a headache (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,runny_nose) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a runny_nose (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a conjunctivitis (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,cough) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a cough (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,body_ache) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a body_ache (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,chills) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a chills (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sore_throat) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a sore_throat (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sneezing) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a sneezing (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,swollen_glands) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a swollen_glands (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,german_measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,flu) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,cough).

hypothesis(Patient,common_cold) :-
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,chills).

hypothesis(Patient,mumps) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,swollen_glands).

hypothesis(Patient,chicken_pox) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose).

write_list([]).
write_list([Term| Terms]) :-
    write(Term),
    write_list(Terms).

response(Reply) :-
    get_single_char(Code),
    put_code(Code), nl,
    char_code(Reply, Code).
```

**And I'm getting the following error:**

No permission to call sandboxed `get_single_char(_1538)'
Reachable from:
response(A)
symptom(A,B)
hypothesis(A,B)
go

**What does this means?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a limitation of https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ ; "sandboxing" means they disable any code which cannot work with a webserver/browser setup, or code which someone could use to attack their server.

SWISH supports [`read_line_to_codes/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_line_to_codes%2f2) so you could try:

```
response(Reply) :-
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, Codes),
    nth0(0, Codes, FirstCode),
    char_code(Reply, FirstCode).
```

Or you can [download SWI-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable) and install it on your computer, then there is no sandbox and you can run any code.

Comment: Thank you @TessellatingHeckler now it runs, but if you could help me one more time...I'm new to Prolog programming and I don't know why when I enter the patients name it doesn't shows correctly on the "Does _10712 have a fever (y/n) ?" question, it appears like that, with random numbers.

Comment: Also sometimes and randomly it asks the same question multiple times when its already answered.

Comment: @LauraGonzález that `_10712` is Prolog showing a variable which has no value yet, e.g. `?- write(X).` shows that because X has no value to show. I suspect if that happens on the fever question, but not the others, maybe a typo in the `Patient` variable? I can't see one in your question but maybe there is one in the code you are running?

Comment: @LauraGonzález I haven't studied how it works in detail, but I wouldn't be surprised if asking the same question again is it backtracking over the options searching for answers; it will try `hypothesis(Patient,measles)` and ask questions, if they do not have measles it will try `hypothesis(Patient,german_measles)` and ask the questions again. I don't know an easy fix, but you might need some way to store "have I asked this question before?" and check that each time before asking again. Maybe with list of Question-Answer pairs, or maybe with `assertz`

Comment: the problem with the random number assignment was because of capital letters, if I write the name in lowercase it works correctly.

Comment: but I can't find the way to make it work without asking the same question multiple times... :( @TessellatingHeckler